# Elastic Search Word Combination Understanding

Tags: elasticsearch

Example: the index contains documents with movie names such as movie_name , movie_name part 2 and movie_name part 3 and so on. For the search query "movie_name part 2" I get the exact document. But how to search for "movie_name 2" such that I get the document "movie_name part 2". I am only getting "movie_name" as result document.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can leverage wild card search concept using regex like below

{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "<field_name>": {
                "value": "^movie_name[a-z A-Z _]*2$"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html